# return a total count of counts in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

The following statement gets row counts for user_ids from various tables/conditions where the users are within specific computers of a specific account.  It works as expected.  An example output would be something like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [computer_name] => COMPUTER_1
            [username] => Steve
            [t1count] => 13
            [t2count] => 
            [t3count] => 23
            [t4count] => 64
        )
    ... and so on for each
```

the statement :

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT c.computer_name, users.username, t1count, t2count, t3count, t4count 
    FROM
        ( SELECT account_id, computer_id, computer_name
            FROM computers
            WHERE account_id = ".$_SESSION['user']['account_id']."
            ORDER BY computer_id ASC LIMIT 0, ".$_SESSION['user']['licenses']."
        ) as c
        LEFT JOIN users
            on users.computer_id = c.computer_id

        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) as t1count
            FROM t1
            WHERE t1.title LIKE 'started'
            GROUP BY user_id) as t_t1
                on t_t1.user_id = users.user_id

        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) as t2count
            FROM t2
            GROUP BY user_id) as t_t2
                on t_t2.user_id = users.user_id

        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) as t3count
            FROM t1
            WHERE t1.title LIKE 'blocked'
            GROUP BY user_id) as t_t3
                on t_t3.user_id = users.user_id     

        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) as t4count
            FROM t1
            WHERE t1.title LIKE 'closed'
            GROUP BY user_id) as t_t4
                on t_t4.user_id = users.user_id

            ... and so on for each

    WHERE c.account_id = ?
");
```

I want to also return a totalsum = t1count + t2count + t3count + t4count in this statement as well, but can't seem to get anything working.  In this situation I cannot do outside processing (adding the values that are returned)... it needs to be in the statement.  I am also open to any suggestions in what I already have if there are better options.

Comment: You can use `foreach` for sum array values.

Comment: Due to other reasons it must be in the statement.

Comment: You prepare but concat `$_SESSION['user']['account_id']` directly into the SQL string? o_O.

Comment: Just select the way you want it: `t1count + t2count + t3count + t4count totalsum` - done.

Comment: Yes, because I could not get bindings to work when inside a select of a select... if you know how then please let me know.

Comment: @user756659: mysqli or PDO? At least properly sanitzie that value, cast to integer for example: `0, ". (int) $_SESSION['user']['licenses']."`

Comment: hakre - that returns one result for all user_id combinations for some reason... one of the things I tried last night.  This is PDO.

Comment: I cannot get it working... that is why I am here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do with these values? `SUM(t1count,t2count,t3count,t4count) AS totalsum` should work to get a count of counts.

Your query is a bit hard to read. You have implicit and explicit `JOIN`s. You are grouping numerous times and pulling columns when you can generally do this all in one shot. If you share an SQLFiddle, I will be able to clean this up, but in short:

```
SELECT 
    c.computer_name, 
    users.username, 
    count(t_t1.user_id) AS t1count, 
    count(t_t2.user_id) AS t2count, 
    count(t_t3.user_id) AS t3count, 
    count(t_t4.user_id) AS t4count, 
    (count(t_t1.user_id)+count(t_t2.user_id)+count(t_t3.user_id)+count(t_t4.user_id)) AS totalsum FROM users
LEFT JOIN computers AS c ON users.computer_id=c.computer_id AND c.account_id=?
LEFT JOIN t1 AS t_t1 ON t_t1.user_id = users.user_id AND t_t1.title LIKE "started"
LEFT JOIN t2 AS t_t2 ON t_t2.user_id = users.user_id
LEFT JOIN t1 AS t_t3 ON t_t3.user_id = users.user_id AND t_t3.title LIKE 'blocked'
LEFT JOIN t1 AS t_t4 ON t_t4.user_id = users.user_id AND t_t4.title LIKE 'closed'
WHERE c.account_id = ?
AND t_t1.title LIKE started
GROUP BY users.user_id;
```

This may need tweaking, as I stated, but it is a lot cleaner and easier to read and should accomplish something very similar.

Alternately, if you can't get the query to run the way you want it to when you change it to entirely explicit joins, rather than using `SUM`, try adding the values together like I did in the example above. It should prevent them from aggregating in the same way.

**EDIT**

After viewing your SQLFiddle, I have doctored up a solution which does away with nested queries. The positive is that it is cleaner. The negative is that it requires you to specify the users using an `IN` clause.

```
SELECT computers.account_id,computers.computer_id,computers.computer_name,users.user_id,users.username,count(distinct t_count1.log_id) AS count1,count(distinct t_count2.log_id) AS count2,count(distinct t_count3.log_id) AS count3, count(distinct t_count4.event_id) AS count4,
(count(distinct t_count1.log_id) + count(distinct t_count2.log_id) + count(distinct t_count3.log_id) + count(distinct t_count4.event_id)) AS totalcount

FROM users
INNER JOIN computers ON computers.computer_id=users.computer_id
LEFT JOIN logs AS t_count1 ON t_count1.type LIKE 'type1' AND t_count1.user_id=users.user_id
LEFT JOIN logs AS t_count2 ON t_count2.type LIKE 'type2' AND t_count2.user_id=users.user_id
LEFT JOIN logs AS t_count3 ON t_count3.type LIKE 'type3' AND t_count3.user_id=users.user_id
LEFT JOIN events AS t_count4 ON t_count4.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE computers.account_id=1 AND computers.computer_id in (1,2)
GROUP BY users.user_id
ORDER BY users.user_id ASC,computers.computer_id ASC;
```

If you choose to keep your current query structure for any reason, adapting it like so should make it work for you:

```
select *,ifnull(count1,0)+ifnull(count2,0)+ifnull(count3,0)+ifnull(count4,0) AS totalcount from
  ( select account_id, computer_id, computer_name
     from computers
     order by computer_id asc limit 0, 2
  ) as c

  left join users
    on users.computer_id = c.computer_id

  left join
    (select user_id, count(user_id) as count1
       from logs
       where logs.type like 'type1'
       group by user_id) as t_count1
    on t_count1.user_id = users.user_id

  left join
    (select user_id, ifnull(count(user_id),0) as count2
       from logs
       where logs.type like 'type2'
       group by user_id) as t_count2
    on t_count2.user_id = users.user_id

  left join
    (select user_id, count(user_id) as count3
       from logs
       where logs.type like 'type3'
       group by user_id) as t_count3
    on t_count3.user_id = users.user_id

  left join
    (select user_id, count(user_id) as count4
       from events
       group by user_id) as t_count4
      on t_count4.user_id = users.user_id

   where c.account_id = 1;
```

My advice would be to follow along each query to understand what you are asking SQL to do. To actually add all values together, you should be counting the number of records that are returned. Counting values of your primary keys helps you to count records. Also, using your other example, `ifnull` in the second example make sure that *null* values are not going to interfere with adding. "If a value is null make it 0 instead."

Comment: I believe that is because `SUM` aggregates, however doing arithmetic calculations per row should do it as I commented above. You say it doesn't, so can't shed any more light.

Comment: No... it is returning all users rather than just those from selected comps(I see this is left out, but is why I had a select for that) and running some tests the values are not even close.  Still playing around with it though.

Comment: I have made updates - this should be able to work without your nested queries. I did leave out a few conditions you had in your initial statements though which would probably help.

Comment: I took some time to create a fiddle, and while it is not exact, it does have all the purposes I need... minus a total of all totals... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f314/1 - if you have time please take a look as it may clear things up.  Thank you for everything so far!

Comment: Awesome - I am interested to see how this can be done as things like this with sql are all new to me within the last few days although I 'seem' to be picking it up.  Hopefully the fiddle made the db setup and what I am trying to do a little clearer.  I think what was confusing is only selecting users from specific computers within the account.

Comment: Thanks.  I will take a better look at this later tonight.  I'm not fond of the IN clause thought because that will require another query to 'lookup' the active ids to use it.

Comment: Well, it works, but it is extremely slow to the point of hanging the server.  I found the issue though... I am using this with DataTables script and the culprit is `"SELECT COUNT(users.user_id)
    FROM $table"
` where $table is the statement.  For a simple 7 user return with basically no data in my test db (counts for rows are less than 20 each) it returns 1,749,605 for this select statement.  Ideas?

Comment: Using the second option (more like my original) does not have this issue although I cannot seem to get `IF(count(user_id) = "(null)",0,count(user_id))` working... `Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '('`

Comment: Typo! Should have been ifnull(). Fixed.

Comment: Any ideas about the other stuff?  For something so simple to return almost 2mill results that tells me something is off... if I am waiting 3 seconds for a few users and basically small counts I can only imagine how long it would be for something larger.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52559/discussion-between-smcjones-and-user756659)